# Read Kafka message and set that message is processing by client

Tags: apache-kafka

Are there any feature in Kafka that client can set e.g. flag or some atribute for message?

User story for this is: Client reads message from Kafka and set flag or atribute for message which logical means "message processing". Client do sth with information e.g. sending to other system. If sending to other system was succesfull then client sets in Kafka's message that message was processed. After that message then shouldn't be get/use by other consumer, message processing was done.

Is it posible with any built in mechanism in kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in Kafka but, there is no concept like marking the message as ***being processed***

A message can be ***committed*** once it is processed, so that no other consumers in the group read that message again (until you manually seek).

If the processing is a heavy operation, you can divide it into steps and write the intermediate results in intermediate topics.

If you are running multiple consumers as a group each of the consumers will get a subset of data (called topic partitions) to work on. So, no consumer belonging to the group interferes with another consumer in its group.

However, in case if one of the consumers in the group dies, any of the other consumers takeover its work from the point where it left off ([see Transactional processing](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)) and process them.

You might be interested in having *[exactly-once processing](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/)* semantics where a message is processed only once.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Consumer Group within Kafka will exactly do what you are trying to achieve:

Each Kafka consumer client is associated to a ConsumerGroup. In addition, each partition of a Kafka topic can be read by exactly one consumer out of the same ConsumerGroup. A ConsumerGroup can have multiple consumers.

If the consumer processed the data successfully, the consumer can commit back to Kafka the offsets. That way other consumers of the same consumerGroup will know that another consumer has already processed the data.

What you need to look at is:

- [ConsumerGroup](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#consumer-groups)
- [Offset Management](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management)

Answer (score 0):

I think not because Kafka messages cannot be changed. But you can do something like it by creating a new topic for these kind of messages.